# How to vertically center TListBox item?

Tags: delphi, listbox, centering, tlistbox

So I want to vertically center the `TListBox` (not `TListView`) item.

I can use `TopIndex` property, but how do I do the whole thing.

If there are fewer items so the scroll bar doesn't appear, then centering is not required, only selection of default item will do just fine.

Something like this:

[image: Vertically Centered TListBox]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
//IF YOU WANT TO SELECT THE CENTER ITEM 
procedure TForm2.Center;
  var VisibleItems : Integer;
begin
  VisibleItems := ListBox1.ClientHeight div  ListBox1.ItemHeight;
  ListBox1.TopIndex := Trunc((ListBox1.Items.Count / 2) - (VisibleItems / 2));
  if ListBox1.Items.Count > VisibleItems then
    ListBox1.Selected[ListBox1.TopIndex + (VisibleItems div 2)] := True
  else
    ListBox1.Selected[ListBox1.Items.Count div 2] := True;
end;



//IF YOU WANT TO CENTER A ITEM
procedure TForm2.Center(Index : Integer);
  var VisibleItems : Integer;
begin
  VisibleItems := ListBox1.ClientHeight div ListBox1.ItemHeight;
  if Index > VisibleItems then
    ListBox1.TopIndex :=  Index - (VisibleItems div 2);
end;
```

Comment: Is it necessary, to compute floating point values? Wouldn't `div` suffice?

Comment: Further, I don't think OP wants to select the vertical center item but rather to vertical center the selected item.

Comment: You're right about div, I changed some parts of the code. If he want's to vertical center the selected item instead of select the vertical center item I'll change or remove this answer.

Comment: @Kohull Thank you!